# Copying last form response to new last row other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am very new to coding with apps script but I am trying to set up a code that transfer the last row of a new google forms spreadsheet submission to another sheet in the same workbook. The reason I am trying to do this is so I can make simple calculations with the data and also edit the data (you can't edit the data with Query functions).

I have one sheet called (Form Responses 1) and one sheet called (Clients). When the form is filled out all the answers are ofcourse automatically transferred to the Form Response 1 sheet. I would like to automatically copy the last row of the Form Response 1 sheet to the Clients sheet so the information can be edited and used in calculations without losing the original submission which will be in Form Responses 1 (not a query).

There are two of the codes I tried with my very basic knowledge and they both do not work. The codes probably suck but any help and advice is greatly appreciated!

**Code 1 that I tried**

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Form responses 1")();
  var copyFromRange = 'Form responses 1!A2:M999';
  var copyToRangeStart = 'Clients!A2:M999';
  copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart);
}
```

**Code 2 that I tried**

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
  var r = s.getRange(s.getLastRow(),s.getLastColumn());
  var data = r.getValues();

  var row = r.getRow();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,20).setValues(data);
```

I have been browsing the website while trying to figure this out and learn more on scripting, you have all been a great help!

Answer (score 0):

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheetByName('Clients').appendRow(e.values);
}
```

[onFormSubmit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

You don't want to get the last row because if submissions come to fast the last row may not be the one from the currrent onFormSubmit trigger.

Comment: I hope you realize that you cannot just run this function from the script editor.  It must have an event object.